# Datastax Cassandra incorrect request for ALLOW FILTERING

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I have a table as below:

```
create table experience.metrics(
            stream varchar, 
            user varchar, 
            computer varchar, 
            experience varchar,
            counter int, 
            PRIMARY(stream, user, computer)
);
```

Also created an index on experience as below:

```
create index metrics_experience on experience.metrics(experience);
```

Now when I query following using cqlsh it works perfectly fine:

```
select * from experience.metrics where stream='streamOne' and experience='success';
```

Note that it does not require ALLOW FILTERING. But when I use the same query from Java using Datstax driver, it complains that query requires ALLOW FILTERING.

My pom has following:

```
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
```

Is this a bug in datastax driver?

Comment: I checked query built with QueryBuilder and cql directly passed to execute method and everything works fine on Cassandra 3.2. Which version of Cassandra you are using?

Comment: 3.5.0 when I execute select release_version from system.local; By the way I am using preparedstatement to execute query if that makes a difference.

Comment: Prepared statement on Cassandra 3.5 also works fine. I can generate `com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING` only when I explicitly drop experience.metrics index. Please check once again if you are using the same keyspace/table/index both from cqlsh and Java code and add source code with prepared statement to your question for further assistance.

Comment: I upgraded Cassandra database and the problem disappeared. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It was working for me when I was using cassandra 3.7 and after upgradation like cassandra 3.11. I am also facing same issue.